# Why I'm still seeing depreciated endpoint for web push notification

Tags: web-push

A small percentage of web push notifications subscriptions through VAPID still returns `android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` endpoint url. I'm under impression that it was depreciated back in 2019. Most endpoints are either from Chrome (fcm.googleapis.com), Firefox or Edge.

What browsers are still returning android.googleapis.com endpoint?

Comment: We also have the same problem. You can see from your server logs the `User-Agent` header if you need more details.

Comment: Do you (or should I ) convert these to the fcm endpoint?